# Modify contents of string literal C++ based on function constraints

Tags: c++, string

I need to convert a given string literal to its lower case by passing the string as an argument to the function Lower(char *). The function can return only int.
In the main() i need the converted string to be accessible somehow. 
Currently i am type casting the address of the tmp string in the Lower() function and then trying to dereference that address.
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int Lower(char* str)
{

char tmp[100];
for(int i=0;i<=strlen(str);i++)
{
   if(isupper(*(str+i)))
     *(tmp+i) = *(str+i)+32; 
   else
     *(tmp+i) = *(str+i);
}
return int(tmp);
}

int main()
{
   char* str = "gOAt";
   char *rc=(char *)Lower(str);
   printf(rc);
   return 0;
}
```

Again the function prototype cannot change ie the prototype must be int Lower(char *). However, "goat" must be somehow accessible in the main() function. How can this be done?

Comment: Questions: why use char * and not use std::string? - what's supposed to be the return value of Lower? I guess it is *not* the lowercase string....

Comment: modifying literals yields undefined behaviour

Comment: How do you expect to get the lowered string when you can't change the prototype and the function returns int? Also as the others said, drop the c-like syntax, the stl was created for a reason.

Comment: The number of things wrong in this already make a strong argument for scrapping it, reviewing the assignment, and starting over. From invalid type casts to returning addresses of automatic variables, the level of "wrong" is approaching critical mass.

Comment: Check for a fixed working sample of your code [here](http://ideone.com/rKWfZs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with the posted code. My take would be that the int returned from the function is a status code, when it's 1, it signals that the conversion to lowercase was successful, 0 otherwise. Here is a working program that does the conversion:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int lower(char* str)
{
    int hasLower = 0;

    while(*str)
    {
        if (*str >= 'A' && *str <= 'Z')
        {
            *str = (*str - 'A') + 'a';
            hasLower = 1;
        }
        str++;
    }

    return hasLower;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    if (argc != 2) { cout << "No input! Exiting..." << endl; return 1; }

    char* input = argv[1];
    if (lower(input))
    {
        cout << "Lower case: " << input << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << input << " isn't a valid string for lower-case conversion" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```